# JQuery modify an element on document.on('blur')

Tags: jquery

Here is a general version of the code I am trying to accomplish (The code is very incomplete, just to give a general idea):

```
$(document).on('blur', '#idofTextbox', function(event) {

  function SaveData(URI, stringVal, success, failure) {
   $.ajax({
    //Initialize json Object here
    });
  }

  SaveData("/myURL", "myString", successFunction, failureFunction);

  function successFunction(response) {
      var successString = 'Valid';
      $('#successMsgTextArea').text(successString);
      $('#successMsgTextArea').removeAttr('class', 'errorMsg');
      $('#successMsgTextArea').attr('class', 'successMsg');
   }

  function failureFunction(response) {
      var successString = 'Invalid';
      $('#successMsgTextArea').text(successString);
      $('#successMsgTextArea').removeAttr('class', 'successMsg');
      $('#successMsgTextArea').attr('class', 'errorMsg');
   }
}); //end of blur event
```

Basically, I have two classes, one has a red X image, the other has a checkmark image.  When a user enters a value, I check if the value is valid by checking if it is in a database.  If it is valid, I first remove the previous class styling (in case it switches from invalid to valid).  Then I display 'Valid' and have a checkmark (by assigning it successMsg class), and if wrong, I display 'Invalid' and have an X besides the message (by assigning it the errorMsg class).  However, when I test this out, the error text is displayed, but the class never gets updated.  Is what I did incorrect?

Comment: This probably isn't the cause of the problem, but you should use `addClass` and `removeClass` to modify an element's classes, rather than `attr` and `removeAttr`.

Comment: Ahh, in my entire time coding in JQuery, I have not even heard of that.  Thanks!